# Cannot create an instance of Oracle Java Cloud Service in Oracle Cloud

Tags: java, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-java-cloud-service

In Oracle Cloud when trying to create an instance of "Oracle Java Cloud Service", in Step 2, a database created in the same account does not show up, this not allowing me to create the instance.

Steps i'm doing:

1. Created a new compartment
2. Created a Oracle Autonomous Database Transaction Processing

```
 General Information
 Database Name: dbtr1
 Workload Type: Transaction Processing
 Compartment: surenk (root)/dbcompartment
 ...
 License Type: License included
 Database Version: 18c
 Auto Scaling: DisabledAuto Scaling
 Lifecycle State: Available
 Instance Type: Free
```

2. Then Platform Services > Java >

in Step 2, the above database does not show up in any compartments

[image]

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a policy for your ATP database to show up in the console:

> Specify this policy if you created the database in a custom compartment:
> `Allow service PSM to inspect autonomous-database in compartment compartment_name`
>
> Specify this policy if you created the database in the root compartment:
> `Allow service PSM to inspect autonomous-database in tenancy`

See docs and other requirements [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/java-cloud/jscug/create-database.html).